# Noncontiguous substring autocomplete without spaces

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, intellij-idea, bootstrap-typeahead

I've seen many questions on SO about jquery autocomplete with multiple keywords or tokens like

"el wo" matches "hello world" (I can't bold the substring matches because of SO's markdown parsing without adding spaces)

I would like to achieve something similar, but without using spaces in the search string. This is used successfully in JetBrains IntelliJ and their other similar products. For example,

`aco` matches not only `aconite` but also `admin_controller`

Is this possible with the jquery and/or bootstrap autocomplete or typeahead plugins? How does IntelliJ do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't check what order the matches are in but you could try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tEJdx/5/

```
var possible = [
    'admin_controller',
    'accommodation',
    'printer',
    'advertised',
    'aoc', // this will match even if it's in wrong order
];

$('input').keypress(function(){
    setTimeout( function() {
        var result = [], input = $('#input').val();
        possible.filter(function(element, index, array) {
            var count = 0;
            for( i in input ) {
                if( element.indexOf( input[i] ) != -1 )
                    count++;
            }
            if( count == input.length )
            result.push( element );
        });

        $('#result').html(result.join('<br/>'));
    }, 200);

});
```

With HTML like this:

```
<input id="input" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks! Hopefully there's a way to keep the substrings in order.

Comment: @tralston if by "in order" you mean have them sorted alphabetically just change result.join('<br/>') to result.sort().join('<br/>')

Comment: No, I meant in the order they occur naturally. So "adc" will match "admin_controller" (ad..min_..c..ontroller) but not "accomodation" (ac..como..d..ation) -- the order of the characters should be preserved as the same order in the input string.